# Robots not dancing while WAV song plays

Tags: python, audio, calico-project

I am working on a project that requires a group of Scribbler 2s to dance at the start of playing a wav file and stop at the end of the file.

(This is not the full code, but rather me testing how to do it so I can apply it to the larger code.)

```
from Myro import *
from winsound import*
from time import *

def playSong():
    s=PlaySound('C:\Python34\cantHoldUs.wav',SND_FILENAME)
    sleep(30)
    s.PlaySound(None,SND_FILENAME)

while playSong()==True:
    motors(-1,1)
```

The song plays and ends, but the robot does not move. Can anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend restructuring your code to something with a While Loop since it's cleaner and easier to control:

```
from time import *

# Play the song
s=PlaySound('C:\Python34\cantHoldUs.wav',SND_FILENAME)

# Start the timer so we can identify when to stop
starttime = time()

# Use a while loop with a True statement until we decide to break it
while True:
    # Make that robot dance!
    motors(-1,1)

    # Check the current time
    stop_time = ((time() - starttime))

    # Stop when 30 seconds is hit
    if stop_time > 30:
        s.PlaySound(None,SND_FILENAME)
        break

    sleep(1)
```

Comment: This does not work--the song plays but the scribbler still does not move. I received the error that time does not exist. I changed it by putting 'from time import time' but that did not work either.

Comment: File "C:\Users\Aesia\Desktop\Elements\Calico-4.0.0-windows-    all(1)\Calico\playmusicTest.py", line 8, in <module>

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'time'

Comment: Have you tried simply using `import time` for time,  which will import everything?

Comment: Yes that is what i had originally and it gave me the same error

Comment: @A.C. That's weird. It works perfectly on mine. I edited the code to incorporate your original design `from time import *`, can you try it now

Comment: Still not working, I'm afraid. Still getting the same error

Comment: @A.C. What did you change to make it work. And did the robot stop dancing after the song stopped based on my code?

Comment: I used import time, but what happened was that the song played, ended, and then the scribbler spun.

Comment: @A.C. I'm not sure if this is ideal, but I placed sleep(1) after the if condition to give time for the motors function to operate. Let's see if that works

Comment: The same result, but now it is saying : `TypeError: 'stop_time' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Comment: @A.C. Can you paste your full code on pastebin so I can examine it? My code is not part of a function, so stop_time cannot be part of an argument. Most likely there's something else going. If you can also try this: Create a loop that'll make the robot spin without music, see if that works.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with pastebin. I have my full code as well as the code I was using for a test below it in the past box. What else do I need to do?

Comment: @A.C. Does the robot spin without the music?

Comment: Yes it spins without the music

Comment: At least we know that works. It could be likely that there is a conflict in program between the windows player and the robot information. Can you paste the code on http://pastebin.com/ and share the URL to the code